# Ryu framework, tcp_flags in parser.OFPMatch

Tags: openflow, ryu

I am trying to match flow in openflow-compatible switch (openflow 1.5) by using ryu framework.

As far as I know, openflow version 1.5 supports 'tcp_flags' match conditions, and Ryu also does.

So, when I am trying to code like:

```
    match = parser.OFPMatch(
        tcp_flags=0x000
        )
```

nothing happens in flow table, while I am expecting to occur a new flow entry.

Ingress packet contains empty value for tcp flags.

Does anyone knows, how to code such kind of condition in a ryu?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
match = parser.OFPMatch(
    eth_type=0x0800, 
    ip_proto=6, 
    tcp_flags=0x000
    )
```

solved my problem. According to 'OpenFlow Switch Specification', before use of 'tcp_flags', some prerequisite fields should be met. In my case, 'tcp_flags' field needs 'eth_type = 0x8000' and 'ip_proto = 6' fields placed before.